# Unable to install Apache Nifi on Windows 10

Tags: apache-nifi

I have installed Apache nifi-1.8.0. I have jdk-11.0.2 installed in my PC. 
I have placed the Nifi folder on path `C:\Demo\nifi-1.8.0` and `jdk` on path `C:\Java`.

I am unable to start Apache nifi.

> C:\Demo\nifi-1.8.0\bin>run-nifi.bat

When I run the above run-nifi command I get the below error:

```
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-api-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -XX:+UseG1GC -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=52205 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\\logs --add-modules=java.xml.bind org.apache.nifi.NiFi
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.util.OSUtils (file:/C:/Demo/nifi-1.8.0/lib/bootstrap/nifi-bootstrap-1.8.0.jar) to method java.lang.ProcessImpl.pid()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.util.OSUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-02-02 11:28:11,093 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2019-02-02 11:28:11,140 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2019-02-02 11:28:11,202 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 7500
```

In nifi-bootstrap.log, I get the following error:

```
2019-02-02 11:28:10,858 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
2019-02-02 11:28:10,890 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
2019-02-02 11:28:10,890 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
2019-02-02 11:28:10,890 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0
2019-02-02 11:28:10,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-api-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.8.0.jar;C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -XX:+UseG1GC -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=52205 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\\logs --add-modules=java.xml.bind org.apache.nifi.NiFi 
2019-02-02 11:28:11,093 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2019-02-02 11:28:11,140 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\Demo\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2019-02-02 11:28:11,202 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 7500
2019-02-02 11:28:11,265 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
2019-02-02 11:28:11,265 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found
2019-02-02 11:28:12,229 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

Answer (score 4):

can't find upper supported java version for nifi in the documentation

but the problem in java 11

downgrade [java to version 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: This is correct, NiFi currently only runs on Java 8